# Почему одно поле меняет свое значение вместе с другим? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица в БД:

```
CREATE TABLE work (
  workId INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  toUserId INTEGER, 
  observerId INTEGER, 
  fromUserId INTEGER,
  startDate TIMESTAMP,
  endDate TIMESTAMP,
  finishDate TIMESTAMP,
  assignment VARCHAR(500),
  mailId VARCHAR(50),
  filePathAndNameToWork VARCHAR(100),
  isComplete BOOLEAN DEFAULT NULL,
  isAccept VARCHAR(10),
  report VARCHAR (500),
  reportFilePathAndNameToWork VARCHAR(150),
  template VARCHAR (50),
  PRIMARY KEY (workId)
);
```

И запрос на редактирование:

```
UPDATE work SET
  isComplete = true, 
  finishDate = now(), 
  isAccept = 'done', 
  report = '+',
  reportFilePathAndNameToWork = 'E:/JavaProjectDocs/uploadDir\reportFile_NPK-1_5_' 
WHERE workId = 5;
```

По идее, запрос на апдэйт никак не затрагивает `startDate`, однако `startDate` и `finishDate` меняются на `now()`, хотя должно только `finishDate`.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: значение по умолчанию у startDate случайно не CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ?

Comment: @sterx, совершенно верно. А какое ему сделать значение по умолчанию? 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Comment: [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html). `DEFAULT 0` либо `DEFAULT NULL`, в зависимости от версии и настроек сервера (explicit_defaults_for_timestamp, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ALLOW_INVALID_DATES).

Comment: Возможно, срабатывает триггер, который не позволяет начальной дате быть больше конечной.

Comment: Всем спасибо! Проблема решена! Выручили!